# FlatList Grid have divide if number column is 3 or 7

Tags: react-native

I want create a FlatList grid have 3 item and don't want add divider line between them so I use code in here
[FlastListGrid3Item](https://snack.expo.io/Hy6uaKPO7)
My item is:

```js
 renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.item}
      >
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

```css
 item: {
    backgroundColor: '#4D243D',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / numColumns, // approximate a square
  },
```

but when run it if it show a divider between item 2 and 3 in row and a divider between column 2 and 3 same photo:

[image]

I test in simulator ipSE
How I can fix it?

Comment: I don't get the divider in snack ios and simulator ios.

Comment: I test in iphone SE and with screen is 320 so when /3 it will return value = 106.066666666666666667 -> have error, if test in iphone 6 ( with is 375 -> /3=125) it don't show divider

Comment: I don't get the divider as [here](https://imgur.com/a/LG83odW)

Comment: Can you show width,height of screen?